# $this->request->input("role") returns all request

Tags: laravel

I have this event to assign role:

```
  <?php

namespace App\Listeners\User;

use App\Events\User\Created;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class AssignRoles
{

    private $request;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  Created  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Created $event)
    {
       $event->user;
       dd($this->request->get('role'));
        // here is the best place to do all the logic about roles that is going to be attached in this user. E.g:
        switch($role = $this->request->input('role')) 
        {

            case $role == 'Asesor':
                $event->user->assignRole('Asesor');
            break;
            case $role == 'Comprador':
                $event->user->assignRole('Comprador');
            break;
            default:
                $event->user->assignRole('Writer');
        }
    }
}
```

but Laravarel doesn't return only "input role", returns always all params in request ¿why?

this is the print message with command dd:

> "_token=7WvSpLbPgRrQ570hcXRnUZiGUOUroXiFLFih1dTa&role=Asesor"

Comment: `$this->request->get('role')` how about this ?

Comment: Try to remove depedency injection from constructor, and remove private property $request, then directly use `public function handle(Request $request, Created $event)` and then do `dd($request->input("role"));` is it same?

Comment: Can you show the class declaration line? Is this a controller or a ServiceProvider?

Comment: I change my post to show you this line MaartenDev

Comment: what about this ? $this->request['role'] ?!

Comment: $this->request->get('role') and $this->request['role'] show me the same, all request.

Comment: a try do which you say, and I dont know how to doing it, whe pass 2 parametres in handle(Request $request, Created $event) show me an error "to few parametres in ..." Lukás Irsák

Comment: dud i check it once again => "$this->request->role" worked for me ( remove dd just use die and see the result )

Comment: I changed dd to die($this->request->role), and get the same result, all the request, I don't understand why.... it's a mistery!

Comment: solved In my view I had old code that passed the entire request. Thanks.